# How can I copy and paste a line from one part of my code to another using python

Tags: python-3.x, paste

```
f = open(FileToBeTested, "r")
lines = f.readlines()

x=lines[LineToBeTested - 1]
paste(x)
```

This is the code I have so far does anyone know a way to take line x and put it into the code to be ran and then taken out when the code is stopped? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use the built-in function eval
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval

```
a = 10
print(eval('a + 1'))
```